# Does OS X support SMB Direct (RDMA)?

Tags: macos, network, smb

SMB over RDMA technology was introduced in SMB 3.0, and gained broader popularity in the last couple of years.

Does anyone know if I can recompile sharing or enable this on macOS?

Comment: Found the only mentioning of this on the internet: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250928702 Linking it here for completeness but not of much help, so still looking for replies and insights.

Answer (score 1):

Well, got this from ATTO tech support today:

> macOS (macOS 10.14.x, macOS 10.15.x Catalina, & macOS 11.x Big Sur)
> does not support SMB Direct, nor RoCE.

:-(

I sent a feature request to Apple. I'm sure that because I said so they'll get right to it.

Comment: Yes - direct writes to memory on the file server! Nothing could possibly go wrong…. (p.s. +1 on both the Q and A - thanks!)

Answer (score -1):

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212277
"In macOS Big Sur 11.3 and later, SMB Multichannel is enabled with default settings that are ideal for most organizations and users, but users can make adjustments as needed." More details follow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: SMB Multichannel is a great addition to SMB, but it and SMB Direct (RDMA) are completely different things.